# Why the need for the MCAS on the Boeing 737 Max 8?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, mcas

Was there a problem with stalling on 737 jets before the 737 Max, if not then why is MCAS needed on the 737 Max 8.If it was a problem why did Boeing wait so long.